# Flip Clock code works on Codepen and doesn't work locally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to test [this code here on CodePen](https://codepen.io/Savassan/pen/vYEeQrX) locally on my laptop.

But it doesn't work! it works fine on codepen but not locally. Why? What I missed?

I created a style.css file and script.js file and index.html file and linked all CDNs and sources... Still nothing...

```js
var huh  = new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 9, 10, 5, 15, 0));
var duh  = new Date();
var wha  = huh.getTime()/1000 - duh.getTime()/1000;

var clock = $('#clock1').FlipClock(1400*12*5, {
    clockFace: 'HourlyCounter',
    countdown: true,
    showSeconds: true
});
```

```css
#clock1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 700px;
    margin-left: -350px; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
    height:100px;
    margin-top: -60px; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
}
```

```html
<!-- Styles of Testimonials Slider -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api.chipware.co.za/js/flipclock-min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<br />
<div class="clock" id="clock1"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do your DevTools show an error, either in the console or in the Network tab?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? You didn't include the linked CSS file: <link href="https://api.chipware.co.za/css/flipclock.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Comment: Voting to close because it's essentially a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to attach the CSS file for the flipclock

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://api.chipware.co.za/css/flipclock.css">
```

Comment: I didn't know there is a feature to include css cdns on codepen... thanks ...